# Determine Strikes on Option Chain

Tags: options, derivatives

Does anyone know how to determine option strikes on an option chain are determined for a specific stock?

I have been searching online and can't seem to figure out how/why the specific strike are set.

2 Stocks can have the same/similar stock prices but the strikes on the option chain for each will be completely different.

Would someone explain why this is so and if possible the formula/process to calculate the strike price?

If possible i would like to calculate these on my own for specific stocks.

Comment: It is dynamic depending on movements in the underlying stock price: "In-, at- and out-of-the-money strike prices are initially listed. New [strikes] are generally added when the underlying trades through the highest or lowest strike price available." Strike Price Intervals are [g]enerally, 2 1/2 points when the strike price is between \$5 and \$25, 5 points when the strike price is between \$25 and \$200, and 10 points when the strike price is over \$200." Source: CBOE

Comment: Also, in the rulebook of NASDAQ under section 5 and with the supplementary material (see [this link](https://listingcenter.nasdaq.com/rulebook/nasdaq/rules/nasdaq-options-4)) you can find the same general rule specified in (d), as specified on the option [specification page of CBOE](https://www.cboe.com/exchange_traded_stock/equity_options_spec/). The supplementary material is quite detailed and specifies some additional rules of the strike price interval.

Comment: It's worth also adding that alongside any general rules that may exist for some exchanges, for others it may be totally arbitrary and decided by the exchange. On top of that, on some exchanges you can request they list new strikes and they'll do it.